# Slanted greater than and equal to, less than and equal to

Tags: equations, relation-symbols

Need to produce a "Greater than" or "Equal to" symbol with a slanted *equal* component of the symbol, i.e. the bottom bar not parallel to the typed line, but parallel to the bottom bar of the right facing arrow.  `\geq` begets a normal "greaterthan"/"equal to"-symbol.  I've found on the internet and then tried `\geqslant`, but it does not work.  I get an error message:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>       l.1171 ...frac{k^{n-1}_1}{k} \right) , n \geqslant
>                                                      1
>       ?

Am I missing something in the preamble?

I assume there is a similar way to achieve a Less than and equal to slant.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596921/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need the `amssymb` package in order to use the `\leqslant` and `\geqslant` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ a-b\geqslant 0 \iff a \geqslant b \iff  b \leqslant a.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks.   I'll be book marking.

Answer (score 12):

There is also `\eqslantless` and `\eqslantgtr` from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  $a \eqslantless b$ $a \eqslantgtr b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!  that was fast!  Works like a champ.  I'm bookmarking this page!